# Inverse KroneckerProduct given other arguments

Tags: vector, tensors, inverse

I'm having problems working out how to do the inverse of a two argument Kronecker Product, given one of the decomposed column vectors.

For example, say I have used the Kronecker Product on two column vectors, and subsequently transformed the components of the first vector, e.g:

```
KroneckerProduct[{{a}, {b}}, {{c}, {d}}]
% /. {a -> e, b -> f}
```

and now want to decompose my new vector back into {{e},{f}} and {{c},{d}}, given that I know the second vector was unchanged. How do I go about this? I have tried using the InverseFunction command, but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by projecting onto the two orthogonal vectors in the product space that have the second factor equal to the unchanged vector:

```
res = 
 KroneckerProduct[{{a}, {b}}, {{c}, {d}}] /. {a -> e, b -> f}

(* ==> {{c e}, {d e}, {c f}, {d f}} *)

p1 = KroneckerProduct[{{1}, {0}}, {{c}, {d}}/(c^2 + d^2)];
p2 = KroneckerProduct[{{0}, {1}}, {{c}, {d}}/(c^2 + d^2)]

(* ==> {{0}, {0}, {c/(c^2 + d^2)}, {d/(c^2 + d^2)}} *)

projector = {{1}, {0}}.Transpose[p1] + {{0}, {1}}.Transpose[p2]

(*
==> {{c/(c^2 + d^2), d/(c^2 + d^2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, c/(c^2 + d^2), 
  d/(c^2 + d^2)}}
*)

Simplify[projector.res]

(* ==> {{e}, {f}} *)
```

Here `res` is the vector in the product space that you start with. We want to extract the coefficients `e` and `f`, knowing they were created by a `KroneckerProduct`. Since the vector containing `c` and `d` is unchanged in the calculation, I define a properly normalized vector `{{c}, {d}}/(c^2 + d^2)` (which in the products `p1`, `p2` would yield unity when dotted into `res` with `a=1`, `b=0` or *vice versa*) and use it to find the coefficients we're looking for by projecting the 4D  vector `res` onto the product of that unit vector with the two canonical unit vectors in the space of the first factor. These two 4D vectors are `p1` and `p2`. The application of these two projections can be turned into a single matrix `projector` that multiplies the amplitudes along the directions of `p1` and `p2` by the unit vectors in the first space to which they correspond.

Comment: If there is no direct inverse function then this is probably the best answer I'm going to get, so thank you!